# How to store the result of exec in a variable

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

How can I store the result of exec in a variable? The output is JSON. 
My SQL query is complex and dynamically generated, so I have to set a variable and execute it.

```
create PROCEDURE dbo.RetrievePerfCounterData @jsonOutput NVARCHAR(MAX) OUTPUT
AS    
BEGIN 
    declare @sql NVARCHAR(MAX)
    SET @sql = ' SELECT TOP (1) getdate() AS ''dateTime'' ,suser_sname()AS ''user'' FOR JSON PATH  '

    exec (@sql)
END
```

Here's my attempt at storing the data in a variable:

```
DECLARE @json AS NVARCHAR(MAX)
EXEC dbo.RetrievePerfCounterData @jsonOutput = @json OUTPUT
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
DECLARE @myVar VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#t1') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #t1
CREATE TABLE #t1 (col1 INT, col2 INT)
INSERT INTO #t1
SELECT 1, 1
UNION
SELECT 1, 2

SET @SQL = 'SET @myVar = (SELECT * FROM #t1 AS T FOR JSON AUTO);' 
EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, N'@myVar VARCHAR(MAX) OUT', @myVar OUT

SELECT @myVar
```

Comment: How does this help the OP here? `FOR JSON` doesn't support setting the value of the variable **inside** the `SELECT`.

Comment: I edited my answer according to your question. output has to be varchar, then you can use different methods to convert json string to a table data.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a subquery:

```
SET @json = (SELECT TOP (1) getdate() AS [dateTime],suser_sname()AS [user] FOR JSON PATH);
```